# TCP port forwarding/tunneling by file sharing

Tags: linux-networking, tcp, port-forwarding

I have a Linux server and a windows client. A folder is shared between these machines with read and write access for both of them.

I want to access a production database from my development machine, normally I do that using ssh port forwarding but in the environment which I'm facing, ssh port forwarding is not available but file sharing is.

Is there any way to forward a port from Linux server to my windows machine like ssh port forwarding but using file sharing? (I think it's theoretically possible but wondering is there any tool for that)

Comment: This sounds *very* much like a [X-Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What end result do you want to achieve?

Comment: @vidarlo I want to access a production database from my development machine, normally I do that using ssh port forwarding but in the environment which I'm facing, ssh port forwarding is not available but file sharing is.

Comment: One might in theory implement a TCP forwarder on top of file sharing. But I would expect the latency to be intolerable for practical use.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich But it's not a built in feature of SMB protocol... As [RFC1149](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers) shows you can run TCP/IP over just about anything that can transport data. But it would require special software on either end.

Comment: @vidarlo: Exactly. It would be similar in concept to [IP over avian carriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers), i.e. use something which is not really suitable as the underlying data layer and somehow make it work by implementing some kind of protocol translation on both client and server side.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich And it makes falcon security a nightmare.

Comment: Even considering you could make a tool on both sides for this (having to handle temporary files for a circular buffer representing network traffic between producer (packet emitter) and consumer (packet receiver) etc.), the actual resolution of the problem is human: you'll have to convince the relevant team: network/security/product owner that what you're trying to do: access production servers as a developer is legitimate and have them grant you such access within the normal available methods that will allow for proper auditing too.

Comment: Either you can't access the environment because somebody has not provisioned that access, or because somebody explicitly does not want you to have that access. While finding a workaround might be OK in the first instance, it is definitely NOT OK in the second instance. You should start by speaking to your local IT.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a program called [File Tunnel](https://github.com/fiddyschmitt/file_tunnel) which lets you tunnel TCP over a file share.

**On your Windows client, run:**

```
ft.exe --tcp-listen 127.0.0.1:5000 --write "\\server\share\1.dat" --read "\\server\share\2.dat"
```

**On your Linux server, run:**

```
./ft-linux-x64 --read "\\media\share\1.dat" --tcp-connect 127.0.0.1:5432 --write "\\media\share\2.dat"
```

Now on your Windows client, connect your database client to `127.0.0.1:5000`

Comment: Interesting, & useful for exfiltrating/back-dooring a compromised environment - but I am very suspicious of this as a tool for BAU traffic.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there any way to forward a port from Linux server to my windows machine like ssh port forwarding but using file sharing?

No, it's not possible. Forwarding traffic is part of the SSH protocol. It's not part of the CIFS/SMB protocol used by Windows' file sharing feature.